# Parallelized Min-Max search algorithm which slows down the whole program

Tags: c, max, openmp, min

In a bigger program, I wrote this piece of code:

```
static void search_minmax(int *min_out, int *max_out,
        const int data[], const size_t stride, const size_t n) {
    /* finds the smallest and largest members of a dataset */

    int min = data[0 * stride];
    int max = data[0 * stride];
    size_t i;

#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(NUM_THREADS) schedule(static) reduction(max:max) reduction(min:min)
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int xi = data[i * stride];

        if (xi < min)
            min = xi;

        if (xi > max)
            max = xi;
    }

    *min_out = min;
    *max_out = max;
}
```

At first look it I thought that it was working, but when in fact, in my program, this algorithm slows down everithing. I cannot see the error. Could someone help me to point it out ?

Comment: I'm confused.  Does the program run correctly but too slowly for your liking ?  Or is the program broken and slow ?

Comment: What values for `n`, `stride`, and `NUM_THREADS` are you using? How many CPU cores do you have? From a cppcon talk, anything beyond 4 threads can saturate the memory bus (i.e. you are bus/CPU bound). The overhead of switching the threads can be a problem

Comment: @CraigEstey: NUM_THREADS=8 and I have 8 cores, n= x millions (it's an image)

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: Results are ok. But program is slower with openmp enabled.

Comment: Are you getting a lot of cache misses? Depending on how that gets broken into threads, that could slow it down a lot.

Comment: Timing is easy.
Without openMP I process 10 images in 2min....
With openmp in 4min

Comment: OK. That's probably bus memory saturation. I've restarted computer with no application and .... results are quite better !!!